# add dynamic route from rails database model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, router

How can I add dynamic route from database, using model activeRecord :

I try : (using Rails 5)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  router = self
  Var.find_by(name: 'pages').value.split(',').each do |page|
    router.get "/#{page}", to: 'application#page', as: page
  end
end
```

but I have an error when I try start rails server :

> `rescue in mysql2_connection': Unknown database 'dale' (ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the code that access the db to initialize block.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  router = self
  Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
      Var.find_by(name: 'pages').value.split(',').each do |page|
        router.get "/#{page}", to: 'application#page', as: page
      end
  end
end
```

There is no guarantee that your initializers will run after all the gem initializers, so any initialization code that depends on a given gem having been initialized should go into a config.after_initialize block.

Rails has 5 initialization events which can be hooked into (listed in the order that they are run): Further details in Rails [documentation initialization events](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is because `Var.find_by(name: 'pages')` is trying to run `ActiveRecord` query, but the `Rails.application.routes.draw` block is executed when the application starts and before the database connection is established.

To solve this, you can move the logic for defining the dynamic routes to a controller action, which will run after the database connection is established. You can then use `redirect_to` in the action to redirect to the appropriate route:

```rb
# in your controller
def pages
  page = params[:page]
  redirect_to "/#{page}"
end

# in your routes file
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages', to: 'application#pages'
  Var.find_by(name: 'pages').value.split(',').each do |page|
    get "/#{page}", to: 'application#page', as: page
  end
end
```

By this way, when a request is made to the `/pages` URL, the pages action will run and redirect to the appropriate route based on the page parameter.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I change for `/:page_name` solution instead, but I open to see other proposition...